# Can I house an audio file on the form?

Tags: delphi

If I have an image file that I want to save to a stream, I can do so by placing an TImage on the form and using it as a container, like so:

```
Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('ExampleFile.png');
Image1.Bitmap.SaveToStream(mybytestream);
```

Is there an equivalent for audio content, some object I can place on the form to house an audio file? If not, how do I use SaveToStream with audio?

Comment: Put the file in the application's resources.

Comment: There is no standard component for holding arbitrary data. Though, nothing stops you from writing your own, I suppose. Otherwise, like Andreas said, just use the application's resources instead, such as via the [Resources and Images](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resources_and_Images) dialog. You can use a `TResourceStream` to access the resource data at runtime.

Comment: Also, I assume you are using FMX, is that right? Because in VCL, `Image1.Bitmap` can't load a PNG file.

Comment: Take a look at the following: [Resource Files Support](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Resource_Files_Support)

Comment: Why are you loading image into your `TByteStream` with the intermediate use of Image component? You do know you can load the mentioned image directly into your `TByteStream` using [LoadFromFile](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TMemoryStream.LoadFromFile) method? You can use the same approach then for loading any file type into `TByteStream`.

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
  var myaudio := TByteStream.Create;
  myaudio.LoadFromFile( 'myaudiofile.mp3' );
  // do something with myaudio data
  myaudio.SaveToFile( 'myaudiofile2.mp3' );
  myaudio.Free;
end;
```

Is this what you're looking for? The example you gave does not "house" the image loaded on the form, so it's hard to decipher your question vs. your example.

Audio files are usually VERY LARGE and you'd want to store a compressed version as a resource in the app. But you'd want to use an audio player that can play a compressed file in the specified format saved in a run-time buffer like a TStream.

Yes, you can use a TImageList to save small images to your form, and it's loaded up when the program starts executing. You could create something like that to hold short audio samples like dings and chimes, but I wouldn't do it for something like an audiobook.

(People often ask how to attach a video to a PDF file, and they don't really think about the fact that the resulting PDF file may easily end up being over a gigabyte in size!)

You're better off having a folder that contains the audio clips, then loading them into an array of streams when the program starts up. That would be the simplest analogy to a TImageList but without the files being saved in the app itself.

An alternative might be to put the audio files into a zip file. Then you could attach the zip file as a resource to the app and extract the files from it. That would make it easier to build the app since you could change the contents of the zip file without having to change your build process at all.

Just be careful of referring to audios by name that might not be there. (This is a common problem that affects the use of fonts that may be attached to an app, and referring to one that's not there.)